# Error with 'pcap-lex' while using make for Android OS compilation

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-emulator, lex

When I run

```
. build/envsetup.sh
lunch full-eng
make
```

I get the following error

```
target Executable: tcpdump (out/target/product/generic/obj/EXECUTABLES/tcpdump_intermediates/LINKED/tcpdump)
prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.x/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libpcap_intermediates/libpcap.a(grammar.o): in function pcap_parse:y.tab.c:1711: error: undefined reference to 'pcap_lex'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [out/target/product/generic/obj/EXECUTABLES/tcpdump_intermediates/LINKED/tcpdump] Error 1
```

I have flex and bison installed.
I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 on a 32 bit machine. 
How do I solve this error?